# Using "Back" button to return to previous layout

Tags: android, button, return, back

What's the code to use the BACK button to return to previous layout/action?? And where should I put it? I'd like the back button the same function that my "Return" button that I created on my app do.

Here's an example:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Return"
    android:id="@+id/voltar"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:onClick="callCho"/>
```

On this example, how would be the code to the "back" button execute the "callCho" metod, which is return to previous layout

EDIT:
Here's how I'm using my created "Return" button to get back to the previous layout and I'd like that cell phone "back" button do the same:

```
//XML File
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Return"
    android:id="@+id/voltar"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:onClick="callCho"/>

//main activity
public void callCho(View v) {
    setContentView(R.layout.choice);
}
```

Comment: The back button should automatically return the user tool the previous screen without any code. Do you mean the "up" button instead?

Comment: I am assuming that if you use fragments you also correctly add then to the back stack.

Comment: When I'm pressing "back" on the Android Studio IDE, the app is closing/hiding

Comment: Add parentActivityName in AndroidManifest.xml file should work.

Comment: Please show how you load each fragment. Are you adding fragments to the back stack as you load them?

Comment: I suggest you read [Providing Proper Back Navigation
](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html) and [Providing Up Navigation](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html) in order to understand the difference between the back and up buttons.

Comment: I edited my post with the code I'm using

Comment: Only activities and fragments are supported by onBackPressed(), you are using normal views which are not supported. You should have a look at fragments. https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: Ohh understood... So there's any other way that I could do that without using fragments?

Answer (score 0):

So you are saying you have implemented the `Return` button and you want your "back" button to behave exactly same?

If so,
Just make sure you overrride `onBackPressed()` method in your activity, do all the handling there and when you press that button, just call `onBackPressed()`

UPDATE:

Do this in your `Activity`:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // do your back button logic here
    // you can have conditions or whatever you want to do.
    // change to different fragment, go to different activity, etc.
}
```

Then, have this method in your `Activity`:

```
public void callCho() {
    onBackPressed();
}
```

This means every time that button is pressed, it will behave like the user pressed the RETURN (BACK) button the phone itself.

**// UPDATE ========>>> Based on comments below:**

`getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();` will work to go back to previous fragment as long as when you start the new fragment, you properly add it to the back stack. Here's an example:

Let's say you are on Fragment X and you want to go to Fragment Y:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(fragmentY, "fragmentY").addToBackStack().commit();
```

Now when you are on fragment Y and you call `getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();`, it will go to Fragment X.

I hope this is clear enough.

You can read more about it here:

https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html#back-fragments

Comment: @Mekillerow that's correct. All you have to do in `onBackPressed()` is change your current view to whichever view you want to go to. A previous activity, fragment from the stack, show a dialog, anything you want

Comment: I got it! But how can I create conditions in the onBackPressed() to return to layout X if I'm on layout Y? Because now the back button is working and every time is returning to the same screen/layout.

Comment: Well that depends on how you have implemented your layouts. I'm guessing you are using Fragments?

Comment: I created for each layout a method and put them on the android:onClick="callLayoutX"

Comment: So if there is a stack of fragments and you want to go to previous one, u can just do this: `getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();`. However if you want to go to a specific one, you can do this and it will return several to choose from: `getFragmentManager().popBackStack()`

Comment: So I just need to put this: getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate(); in the onBackPressed action?

Comment: @th3pat3l Isn't that what the back button does by default? Why does the OP need to write any code?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice it does but Mekillerow wants to use actual hardware back button as well as a button that he created in XML. i am just showing how to get more control over it

Comment: @Code-Apprentice He needs the code because I am not sure how he is changing his layouts. when the current back button is being pressed, the activity finishes and application closes

Comment: Edited my post with the code I'm using to go to previous layouts

Comment: @th3pat3l The inicial code that you showed me worked pretty well, but like I said, every time that I used the phisical "back" button, it was returning to the same layout. There's a way I could do something like that: If I'm on layout X, go back to layout Y" using your first code? It's something like creating a condition inside the "back" button, you got it?

Comment: @Mekillerow i understand what you are saying and even if you find a way to make that work, you can't control all the scenarios. Do proper fragment implementation. Don't call `setContentView`

Comment: Ok, don't know how to do that, I started programming recently... Do you have any link to a well explaneid tutorial/video about it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using setContentView() to change screens. The correct way is to create a separate Activity or Fragment for each screen. With separate Activities you will get back button functionality for free. With fragments you need to do a small amount of extra work when you load the fragment, but you do not have to write any code to respond to the back button directly.